# Why can't I flag an accepted answer with 100 up-votes?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, answers, flags

There's [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646036/javascript-preloading-images/3646056#3646056) for a question titled *[JavaScript Preloading Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646036/javascript-preloading-images)*.

Here is the complete answer:

> *"Yes. This should work on all major browsers."*

That's it. There's nothing else to the answer.

Here is a screenshot of what the answer looks like from my browser:

> [image: Screenshot of answer.]

I can only share or edit this answer.

I'm using Firefox Quantum 65.0.1 (64-bit), and I've even disabled my extensions, because I thought something was being blocked because of them:

> [image: Proof of extensions disabled.]

But the problem still exists.

If I go to another answer I ***can*** flag it:

> [image: Answer I can flag.]

What's wrong, is it my browser, Stack Overflow or the answer?

Also, is it me or are there parts of that answer that are missing? Surely that can't be the full answer.

Comment: That's **not** spam by any definition. And it's not "not an answer" either, nor very low quality, nor needs moderator intervention. The system is making you a favor by not letting you flag it.

Comment: @yivi I can understand how some might think it isn't spam, but an answer that only contains one sentence that doesn't attempt to answer the question definitely isn't an answer.

Comment: SPAM == Unsolicited advertisement. So please, drop that approach. And how this woudln't be an answer? It's answering the question directly. You may want to read this: [When to flag an answer as not an answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer)

Comment: The question asks if the code they have will work on all browsers, and the answer says "yes, it does". So how does that not answer the question? If you think it is a bad/incomplete answer, downvote it.

Comment: All that being said, even if **you shouldn't be flagging that answer**, no idea why the link is not shown. It's not explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts).

Comment: 1. Have you flagged it before? 2. Can you see it if you use another browser or log in in incognito mode?

Comment: By the way (not related to this issue), if this is not your first flag then check your flag history to see if there's any declined flag, to see if you're using flags the wrong way.

Comment: After a declined spam flag (and probably any other flag) you can still see the flag dialog (but not retract the declined flag), e.g. [screnshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcSdS.png).

Comment: See from this point: If someone asks you if they would get burned when they put their hand in boiling water, you would say `yes` and that would be sufficient. Obviously you could give him additional medical information and why water starts bioling at a certain temperature but a `yes` still anwers his question ;)

Comment: The answer still has some uncertainty about it: "it *should* work...". That reads more like an educated guess. I understand that one cannot check *all* browsers, but with some qualifier (that is already there) the answer can be really affirmative (like "Yes, it works on all major browsers"). It is not enough reason to vote to close though. Short answers are really nice when they answer the question.

Comment: @WaiHaLee what if you then flag as NAA and retract that as well?

Comment: @CalvT the same - [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXmE2.png)

Comment: @WaiHaLee I meant [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DanNa.png) - I've retracted a spam flag, a NAA and a mod flag, all on the same answer. Interesting to see you can always submit a mod flag even after retracting one. That's also on a low rep account, so no repro for me as well.

Comment: @CalvT - I see. I took the screenshot from an existing, retracted flag that didn't have a retracted spam flag on it. I didn't flag and retract in case a moderator happened to come across the post I was looking at, and decline the flag. Plus, I like to keep my declined flag count low.

Comment: How a _one liner that too without any explanation_ can have that many up votes ?

Comment: @Achal I think the vote counts can be merely understood as "I agree with that claim", than to say "this is a useful and elaborate answer". Similar as to here in meta

Comment: @Achal, Is the question legitimate? Yes because it can be hard to know if the image were preload or not. Does it answer the question? Yes, the answer is yes, both yes. What are other answer doing? Trying to upgrade or propose alternative to a working solution. Imo all came from the difficulty to test the preloading of Image. And the simplicity of the question.

Comment: I don't think it's a good answer, because a) it sounds like a guess due to "should" b) it does not define what a "major" browser is c) anyone reading it needs to consider the date was 2010. The answer were much better if the statement was "I tested on IE 10, Edge 2, Chrome 27.12, FF 42.18, Opera 9 and it worked on all those browsers on Windows Vista, 7 and 8.1", even with JavaScript disabled ;-) Like that it would be a reproducible statement with the possibility of validating it.

Comment: I don't think the problem here isn't so much the answer, but the question. It could have been phrased differently than a yes/no question. For example: "if not, which browsers might be problematic". But well, a good answer saying "yes it will work" should probably say why, with some manner of reference.

Comment: That answer is from 2010. An answer that short wouldn't be okay today, but it was fine back then. Remember to take historical context into account.

Comment: @TiiJ7 "So how does that not answer the question?" We usually expect more than a simple yes or no from an answer to "Is X possible", otherwise we would have just created a poll. The answer could be made much more helpful by citing relevant sources.

Comment: @SomethingDark "An answer that short wouldn't be okay today, but it was fine back then. Remember to take historical context into account." Taking the historical context into account, I would say that it may have been kind of fine back then, but is not really okay now. I mean that we have to judge all the content by today's standards and should not treat anything different, just because it has a certain age. The context may change our understanding of the motivations of the peoples actions of back then, but it should not change our current days voting patterns.

Comment: @SomethingDark It wasn't considered any better then than it is now. I've seen similar answers from that period get the treatment.

Comment: By that logic, we should just nuke anything from before 2016.

Comment: Ignoring all the discussion on whether you should be flagging that answer or not, I personally do get the option to flag the answer which is why this looks strange. Are you still not able to flag it today? Is it possible you went over your flags limit?  Does it happen in all browsers?

Comment: The correct response would be to downvote the answer, and possibly mod-flag it indicating it's VLQ. It's not spam and it's not NAA.

Comment: This is how democracy works. 100 people cannot be wrong, even if they claim 2+2 equals 5.

Comment: @SomethingDark "By that logic, we should just nuke anything from before 2016." The content from then is not so bad and can still be improved. Why should something get a special protection just because it's old? Just judge every content only by its quality.

Comment: @Trilarion, because no one have to be punish for breaking a law that didn't exist when the "crime" was commited. Quality standard changed. How do you handle quality standard that you are not aware of .

Comment: @xdtTransform I understand your argument but I disagree that there is really a punishment. Voting is absolutely free. If you ask me, we could stop displaying funny numbers below authors names to mitigate the problem.

Comment: Maybe you have flagged it *before* and are not allowed to flag it *twice*?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your experience from a sockpuppet with 16 reputation.

[image: 16 rep cannot repro]

Comment: Beware of declaring about your sockpuppet account. Community user is always active :)

Comment: @ParthPandya It's ok as long as there's no cross voting / other thing you can't do with a single account.

Comment: @ParthPandya don't worry, if the sock puppet does anything shady Madara can just nuke it and suspend the main user.

Comment: @user202729 I actually did cross-vote for it to reach 16 rep :D I've deleted the question immediately after though.

Comment: I also cannot replicate with my ~1900 rep.

Comment: Also [status-no-repro] on FF 65.0 with several plugins that have caused various problems elsewhere.

Answer (score 27):

Flagging that answer should work on all major browsers.

Comment: I see what you did there.

Comment: *tries to flag it* whilst upvoting it.

Comment: Heeey, don't downvote it! How am I going to get to 100 if y'all keep doing that?

Comment: Flagged as not an answer to 'why'? :P

Answer (score 15):

While I am not able to say why you can't flag that answer. (I am not able to reproduce your problem; I have the option to flag it) You really shouldn't. It does answer the question. It is not malicious. It is not a link only answer.

Answers do not have to be several paragraphs of text, to be valid.

Comment: I think most are commenting why this answer should __not__ be flagged, with valid rationale.  However, the original question is __why__ it can not be flagged (by the OP's account).

Answer (score 11):

You can't say that it is a super good answer, but there is no reason to flag this. The question asked if the code would work, the answer said it does, nothing else need be said.

**However, note that on my browser (Google Chrome), I am able to flag the answer if I would wish to:**

> [image]

Comment: It worked for me as well in FF65.0.2 and FF66.0 (windows x64).

Comment: I can flag it from edge 1803 as well

Comment: Would you say you can flag it... in all major browsers?

Answer (score 1):

That's not the case for me. Also, I cannot reproduce your problem here I am adding a screenshot showing the flag button available on the post:

[image: StackOverflow Post]

I can flag that too. But not going to do so because of the question itself asks that. That question was type of a simple yes/no question. That's why it would be unworthy to flag that post.

Another thing, even [Cody Gray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/366904/cody-gray)♦ has written a note there telling not to flag that post.

> **Moderator Note**: Please stop flagging this as "not an answer". It is, in fact, a direct answer to the question that was asked. If you think the answer is wrong, or insufficiently supported with evidence, then downvote it. - Cody Gray♦

And for your question, I can not reproduce the problem.